# How to fix Pull requests after a push --force disaster?

Tags: git, github, push

Ok I had 4 branches mirrored. 2 of them were main branches.

I wanted to rebase one my feature branches with a main branch. So I did this after running rebase command

```
git push --force
```

while having my feature being the working branch.

This caused problems and pushed to all branches because my git config setting was "matching"

Had not been long since this had happened, so we were able to revert all branches to where they were.

However, I am now noticing the pull requests are now showing more commits than they should. I am sure this is the side affect of the disaster. How to fix those pull requests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you truly restored the repository branches to what they were before the disaster, then anyone who didn't do any pulling during the disaster shouldn't have any problems doing new pulls. It's possible that some developers pulled the forced material from the repository during the disaster. So then they will have a problem again when they pull from the fixed repository.

The thing to do in this situation is to avoid the `git pull` command. The rewritten histories cause the rebases and merges to go haywire with unnecessary conflicts.

Everyone should do a `git fetch` to pick up the repository material without doing anything with their working copy and then deal with the situation appropriately.

Suppose I'm on a branch called `master` (without loss of generality). I do a `git fetch` (since I've been told there has been history rewriting upstream) and then type `git checkout` to get an idea of the damage. I see a message like:

> your branch and origin/master have diverged and have 17 and 25 different commits, resp.

Okay. So this means that the upstream history has been rewritten back from the point 17 commits ago (from the p.o.v. of our local `master`). Now, suppose I happen to know that four of the commits on `master` are new, local commits of mine.  Of course I know this because when I do a `git log`, I know what is mine!  (Also, I happen to remember that prior to the `git fetch` which brought in this mess, Git was telling me that my `master` is ahead of `origin/master` by 4 commits.)

> If this was someone else's mess, and I didn't know what commits to keep, I would compare `git log` and `git log origin/master` to see where the duplication begins, and assume that anything on `master` which is more recent than the duplicated commits is a precious change that needs to be retained.

All I care about is preserving those four changes. What I want to do is to make `master` look like the rewritten `origin/master`, **plus** my four changes.

There are multiple ways to do this. Here is a very simple one:

```
git rebase HEAD~4 --onto origin/master
```

Done! We have taken the top four commits, and migrated them over onto `origin/master`, and planted the result in place of the master branch. (By the way, I suspect the `--onto origin/master` argument is redundant since we are on `master` and `origin/master` is its upstream! So it could be as simple as `git rebase HEAD~4`.  "Put four commits into the lifeboat and head for the non-sinking ship!")

Note that if we had done a `git pull --rebase`, then it would have done the equivalent of:

```
git fetch   # master and upstream diverge: 17 versus 25
git rebase  # all 17 commits are being rebased over top of the upstream 25, OOPS!
```

With `rebase HEAD~4`, we are limiting the scope of the rebase to just cherry picking those commits that we know are the ones that are our commits that need to be rebased, and not the 13 remaining commit which are replicated among those upstream 25 and will cause merge problems.  The remaining 13 are abandoned.   Our four changes are replayed over `origin/master`, and that becomes the new `master`.

> Note that sometimes the naive rebase *can* work! For instance, suppose that the rewritten history of the 25 commits does not actually make any changes to the file content, but only to commit messages, authors and time stamps. In that case, git can work it out. This happens all the time, for instance, with the review tool Gerrit. When your submitted Gerrit changes are merged, they are still in your local repo. When you do a `git pull`, you bring in the merged versions of exactly the same commits, but under different hashes.  Git works out that you already have the same commits locally too, and they disappear in the rebase.